# --with-memory-manager=none flag for mpi compiling

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, mpi, openmpi

Normally, when I want to compile a source with mpicc i use the following command:

```
 mpicc -o source source.c
```

However I am experiencing some trouble compiling my current source, some seg faults. I have found on a forum that my problem would be caused by an openmpi bug, that can be somewhat solved by adding the following flag: --with-memory-manager=none. How should the compile command look like, with this flag. I have tried in a few ways but the command doesn't seem to be recognized. Could you please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's a configuration option that needs to be provided in the configure step when you're compiling OpenMPI from source.  It's not something that you can specify when you're compiling an MPI application.

See http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building for more information about building OpenMPI from source, if you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear from configure --help, but I just happened to be looking into this and found the correct flag is --without-memory-manager

Comment: Could you explain your answer? How one should use this when compiling an MPI application? And why this flag?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about recompiling openmpi.  It wasn't clear what bug you were trying to overcome though, so its hard to be more help.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't clear. Therefore I have no idea how you can know that he needs `without` and not `with` when he says he needs `with`. His question was where to place that option and the other answer describes that correctly.

Comment: --with-memory-manager=none or --without-memory-manager are simply two ways of accomplishing the same thing.